# null is not an object in react native while using Datetimepicker

Tags: react-native, typeerror, datetimepicker

I tried reat-native-community/datetimepicker but it says type-error: Null is not an object.
I basically copied and pasted the code but also it shows error. Kindly help. Kindly help it hass been bugging me since yesterday.

My DOB.js file is :

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import { View, Button, Platform } from "react-native";
import DateTimePicker from "@react-native-community/datetimepicker";

export default class DOB extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
     this.state = {
      date: new Date().toLocaleString,
      mode: "date",
      show: false,
    };
  }

  onChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
    const currentDate = selectedDate || date;
    setShow(Platform.OS === "ios");
    setDate(currentDate);
  };

  showMode = (currentMode) => {
    setShow(true);
    setMode(currentMode);
  };

  showDatepicker = () => {
    showMode("date");
  };

  showTimepicker = () => {
    showMode("time");
  };
  render() {
    const { showDatepicker, date, mode, onChange } = this.state;
    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          <Button onPress={showDatepicker} title="Show date picker!" />
        </View>

        {show && (
          <DateTimePicker
            testID="dateTimePicker"
            value={date}
            mode={mode}
            is24Hour={true}
            display="default"
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        )}
       </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Might not resolve your problem, but `toLocaleString` is a method. It should be `(new Date()).toLocaleString()`

Answer (score 0):

Use this way because you're using Hooks in class component

```
<Button onPress={this.showDatepicker} title="Show date picker!" />
```

> Note: setShow() and setDate() are not methods defined